# sort lines of a file alphanumerically

Tags: linux

I have a text file in linux. I want to sort each line w.r.t. other line alphanumerically. Linux sort command 'sort ' does not sort alphanumerically. File is not column based. Specifically I want below two files to match in diff comparison but I am unable to do so. Can you help?
First file content is

```
        2. Scope: /tb/srflop_inst, File: ./aaa/bbb/abc.xyz(155)
            Model: Default AG output
                1. /tb/srflop_inst/srff_q1
                2. /tb/srflop_inst/srff_q2
```

Second file content is

```
        2. Scope: /tb/srflop_inst, File: ./aaa/bbb/abc.xyz(155)
            Model: Default AG output
                1. /tb/srflop_inst/srff_q2
                2. /tb/srflop_inst/srff_q1
```

Comment: `sort` sorts lexicographically. How is that different from alphanumerically?

Comment: You want it to sort the lines with `srff_q1` and `srff_q2`, but not change the numbers at the beginning? I think you'll have to write a `perl` script to recognize these lines, put them into an array, sort it, and then write them out with sequential numbers.

Comment: Can't you fix the program that's creating these files so that it sorts that list?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: You could use head, tail to split file into lines to be sorted, and sort has a "-n" option, as well as a column option. But @Bamar's answer is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to do sort in the program that is generating this output.